# binding dropdown list values

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

used these throughout my app but hitting a problem with this one.

I have these two models:

```
    public class vwLkUpDepartmentCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int DepartmentCategoryID { get; set; }
  public string DepartmentCategory { get; set; }
    public Byte IsActive { get; set; }
}


public class vwDimDepartments
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentCategory{ get; set; }
    public string Departments { get; set; }
    public Byte IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

in the controller i am setting the dropdownlist for values in a viewbag

```
ViewBag.DepartmentDropDown = new SelectList(db.vwLkUpDepartmentCategory.Where(x => x.IsActive == 1).ToList(), "DepartmentCategoryID", "DepartmentCategory");
```

in the view i have

```
 <div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentCategoryID)</div>
                    <div>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DepartmentCategoryID, new SelectList(ViewBag.DepartmentDropDown, "DepartmentCategoryID", "DepartmentCategory"), "", new { @class = "dropdown", id = "txtDepartmentCategoryID" })</div>
                    <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentCategoryID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</div>
```

but when i run it i am getting a error saying

```
DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'DepartmentCategoryID'.
```

Is this because i have the departmentId as the key value in the view?

If I don't explicitly define the departmentCategoryID field in the view it takes the first departmentid and uses that always.

What is the best way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on Controller::

```
 ViewBag.DepartmentCategoryID= new SelectList(db.vwLkUpDepartmentCategory.Where(x => x.IsActive == 1).ToList(), "DepartmentCategoryID", "DepartmentCategory");
```

on View::

```
 <div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentCategoryID)</div>
                        <div>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DepartmentCategoryID, SelectList(ViewBag.DepartmentCategoryID, new { @class = "dropdown", id = "txtDepartmentCategoryID" })</div>
                        <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentCategoryID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</div>
```

Comment: Had to add new in front of the SelectList on the view an add an ) after ViewBag.DepartmentCategoryID to run the code but it has't fixed it.  IT now returns a drop down with System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem

Comment: use `<div>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DepartmentCategoryID, (SelectList)ViewBag.DepartmentCategoryID, new { @class = "dropdown", id = "DepartmentCategoryID" })</div>`

Comment: Thanks, while this displays the right categories in the drop down, it isn't capturing the right ID.  It is taking the first value of the CategoryID and using it that for some reason.

Comment: renamed some of the id's and it is working.  Not sure if there was some conflict behind the scene